# Firefox Quantum responsive design mode: settings for align left & default size?

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

I just upgraded to firefox quantum and am unhappy with the changes to responsive design mode.  I can't find any settings to configure things manually, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

1) The responsive window is now centered in the browser, rather than being aligned left as it was previously.  This really messes with my workflow/window positioning for development.  Is there a way to align the responsive design mode window to the left?

2) The responsive design mode window always opens at 320 x 480.  In previous versions of firefox it would open at whatever size was last used.  Any way to change this?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

1) Locate your profile folder (navigate to `about:support` and click button near "Profile Folder")

2) create or locate folder `chrome` there and create or locate file `userContent.css` in it

3) paste following code there

```
@-moz-document url("chrome://devtools/content/responsive.html/index.xhtml")
{
  #app {align-items: flex-start !important; }
}
```

4) restart browser

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  Any suggestions regarding my second question above?

Comment: Just updated to Firefox Quantum 60.0.1 and the fix above no longer seems to work.

Comment: @dadra Oops, it should be `flex-start`, not `left`; strange it worked up to this point. Thanks for the headsup, corrected.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be working either.  It looks like maybe changes to userContent.css aren't getting picked up at all anymore.  I tried some other edits to test it out and no style changes are showing in the RDM window.  Thoughts?

Comment: Well, you are right, tried now with 60.0.1 and userContent.css seems to be really ignored completely. (I'm usually running Nightly, where it works well for me, ATM.) From quick search there were such regressions around introduction of e10s, but haven't found anything recent yet.

Comment: OK, thanks.  So first Mozilla made RDM horrible, and now they've taken away our ability to even fix one annoying part of it.  Gotta wonder what's up with all that.  I look forward to hearing if there's a fix.

Comment: I got it working again in 60.0.1, but it seems it was just my mistake: for whatever reason I got the `chrome` folder located in `(OS user)\AppData\` **Local** `\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\(test)` (which presumably holds temp/caches only); moving it to the **Roaming** (which the `about:support` points to) fixed the issue for me. (For Nightly I use single profile folder outside OS user structure, so that's why it worked all the time.)  Could to check unlikely scenario something similar happened to you as well?

Comment: Thanks for checking that out. I double checked, and userContent.css is located in the chrome folder that about:support points to. Not sure what's going on, but since the update to 60.0.1 userContent.css seems to be ignored.

Comment: Update.  It's working now.  I can't think of any changes I made that fixed it, but the RDM window is now aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there does not seem to be any option to set a default device for Firefox Quantum RDM - I will file a bug/issue for this and keep you updated!